# NSNotification argument in NSNotificationCenter method is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

I have this really unexplained problem with `NSNotification` method.

I have been using `NSNotificationCenter` for  a long time but i can't explain why this is happening.

My problem is this,

I have a UITableViewCell subclass where i send a `NSNotificationCenter` method to the `UIViewController` when a user taps a button in the cell.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MOVE_TO_PROGRAM_VIEW
                                                    object:self
                                                  userInfo:@{INDEX_ROW : [NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.tag]}];
```

Where the `self.tag` is the row (for the data model in the controller).

In the controller i register for the notification in `viewWillAppear:` like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(userWantsToGoToProgramView:) name:MOVE_TO_PROGRAM_VIEW object:nil];
```

I also remove myself in the `viewWillDisappear:`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MOVE_TO_PROGRAM_VIEW object:nil];
```

Now in the method for the notification i try to get the userInfo and the row but the `notificaiton` argument is nil for some reason..

```
- (void)userWantsToGoToProgramView:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // notification is nil here


    // get the index of the video in the feed
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    NSInteger videoIndex = [userInfo[INDEX_ROW] integerValue];
    NSDictionary *videoData = self.feed[videoIndex];

}
```

Any advice of help will be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: I can't explain your problem, but why are you even using a notification for this purpose? Why not use the button's action method directly? You can get the indexPath of the row the button was in using indexPathForRowAtPoint:, or using the button's tag.

Comment: This is a subclass of uitableviewcell. And I need to let the uiviewcontroller that a button in a this cell was pressed so I can segue to another view controller. But that is not the main issue, this specific problem could be solved with a few other approaches. I do want to know why is this happening (I have also created another Notificationcenter method that don't work also, this means I have a problem is the apps architecture somewhere..)

Comment: How are you determining that the notification is nil? It makes no sense that notification could be nil but notification.userInfo is not nil.

Comment: I have placed a breakpoint when the callback method gets called and it is nil

Comment: OK, sometimes the debugger gives spurious results. If you log notification, I'm sure you'll find that it is not nil.

Comment: Hi, i've logged the notification and found out it is of type NSConcreteNotification, i found it is a private class of NSNotificaiton that i'm not spouse to get..

Comment: NSNotification is a class cluster, so the fact that you get a NSConcreteNotification is fine. That's what I get too. Don't worry about it.

Comment: ohh ok, but for some reason the "userInfo" is empty there

Comment: You said in your question that you got the useInfo, so now you're saying that you don't?

Comment: no, sorry my writing is a bit misleading i'll edit that. The user info is nil